# How to get two matrices/vectors in the same equation?

Tags: equations, matrices

Why is this code not working and how can I get it to work? I would like to multiply one row vector with a column vector.
Here is what I've tried:

```
\begin{equation}

    {\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & x & y
    \end{bmatrix}}

    {\begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3
    \end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation}
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There are several problems.  Most important, blank lines aren't allowed in math; if you want some visual space in the input, put a `%` at the beginning of that line.  Also, the extra braces aren't needed around the `bmatrix` environments.  Finally, it's not so important here, but the LaTeX syntax recommends braces around subscripts; that is, `\alpha_{1}`; This is essential for subscript values that aren't single characters.

Answer (score 8):

No blank lines are allowed inside the code for a math display. The outer braces are redundant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & x & y
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\ \alpha_{2} \\ \alpha_{3}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This MWE to have the same thickness between the two matrices using the package `mtpro2` version `lite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & y  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{1} \\ \alpha_{2} \\ \alpha_{3} \end{bmatrix} 
= 0.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]